# Apache Poi cell not returning the correct value

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel file with a cell that generates the number `3.69` (based on calculations from proceeding numbers)

However when pulling that number in java using

```
if (brightCell.getNumericCellValue()) > 0 )
        {
            double brightness = brightCell.getNumericCellValue();
            return brightness;
        }
```

I've also tried:

```
if (Double.parseDouble(brightCell.getStringCellValue()) > 0 )
{
    double brightness = Double.parseDouble(brightCell.getStringCellValue());
    return brightness;
}
```

`brightCell` is instantiated with :

```
brightCell = spreadsheet.getRow(new CellReference(brightString).getRow()).getCell(new CellReference(brightString).getCol());
```

`brightString` is `String brightString = "BV29"`

But with both solutions, `brightness` receives the value, `3.2133....`

Comment: Does your cell contain a formula? Please try [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html)

Comment: @IgorKudryashov I gave that a try but there's a lot of cells that need to be evaluated so I used `evaluateAll` which returned the error: `workbook environment has not been setup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Igor I managed to figure it out but it led to more issues.

So the solution was creating an evaluator

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(true); //if you need it
```

when you finish setting the required cells and want to evaluate.
`evaluator.EvaluateAll();`

The problem for me is I'm doing this multiple times and my 1st resut is correct but upon the second iteration it becomes skewed, and more skewed.

What I'm doing is setting various cells (via java) then before I retrieve the value for a cell (that contains a formula) I run `EvaluateAll`. Now, I'm not sure if I should be evaluating after EVERY change or after I make all my changes to the excel sheet (via java).

I can't evaluate a specific cell at a time because there's over 38 sheets with multitudes of formulas. So `EvaluateAll` is the best option for me

**EDIT 26/10/2018***
So the issue was not clearing the cache after making inputs. The solution was after each input as specified in the javaDoc that:

```
Should be called whenever there are changes to input cells in the evaluated workbook.
Failure to call this method after changing cell values will cause incorrect behaviour
of the evaluate~ methods of this class
```

therefore after making an input on a cell you should call `evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();`